# How to make collapsible list in sidebar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make collapsible list in sidebar. On click i'm changing "isOpen" state and depending on this state I'm displaying or hiding sub links. The problem is that all sub links opening at same time .

Check sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-moore-h16g6

```
const Sidebar = ({ title, children, data, opened, ...attrs }) => {
  const [isOpen, setTriger] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = idx => {
    setTriger(!isOpen)
  };

  return (
    <SidebarUI>
      {data.map((item, idx) => {
        return typeof item.data === "string" ?
        <div key={idx} >{item.name}</div>:
          <Fragment key={idx}>
            <div onClick={() => handleClick(idx)}>{item.name}</div>
            { item.data.map((subs, ids) => {
              return <Test isOpen={isOpen} key={ids}>++++{subs.name}</Test>;
            })}
          </Fragment>
      })}
    </SidebarUI>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating an object with the state of the collapsed elements, like this:

```
const Sidebar = ({ title, children, data, opened, ...attrs }) => {
  const [collapseElements, setCollapse] = useState({});

  const handleClick = idx => {
    const currentElements = Object.assign({}, collapseElements);

    setCollapse({ ...currentElements, [idx]: !collapseElements[idx] });
  };

  return (
    <SidebarUI>
      {data.map((item, idx) => {
        return typeof item.data === "string" ? (
          <div key={idx}>{item.name}</div>
        ) : (
          <Fragment key={idx}>
            <div onClick={() => handleClick(idx)}>{item.name}</div>

            {item.data.map((subs, ids) => {
              return (
                <Test isOpen={collapseElements[idx]} key={ids}>
                  ++++{subs.name}
                </Test>
              );
            })}
          </Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </SidebarUI>
  );
};
export default Sidebar;
```

Checkout [the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-engelbart-s4x3x?fontsize=14).

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks it works. Could you please explain this string. Right now I have no chance to consolelog it. But i'm curious what it does   `
setCollapse({ ...currentElements, [idx]: !collapseElements[idx] }); };`

Comment: No problem. Basically what it does is it takes the previous collapsible elements (`...currentElements`) and adds the clicked element with its new value (true/false) in its corresponding position (`[idx]: !collapseElements[idx]`). Try adding a `console.log({ ...currentElements, [idx]: !collapseElements[idx] });` before the call to `setCollapse` in order to log the state object

Answer (score 1):

## Edit:

I made a new [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/open-and-close-list-with-transition-f4k24) wich I added some transitions. Now open and closing are smooth.

---

Check [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-currying-nhc03)

Now it opens and closes.

What you have to do is keep what `index` you clicked and only display the children when it's the same `index`.

I also added a way to close and open.

Here is doing that with the code from your question.

```
const Sidebar = ({ title, children, data, opened, ...attrs }) => {
  const [openedIndex , setTriger] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = idx => {
    // this ternary makes it possible to open and close 
    setTriger(idx === openedIndex ? -1 : idx)
  };

  return (
    <SidebarUI>
      {data.map((item, idx) => {
        return typeof item.data === "string" ?
        <div key={idx} >{item.name}</div>:
          <Fragment key={idx}>
            <div onClick={() => handleClick(idx)}>{item.name}</div>
            {// here you check if the idx is the same as the opened one}
            {// before showing the data of the item}
            {idx === openedIndex && item.data.map((subs, ids) => {
              return <Test isOpen={true} key={ids}>++++{subs.name}</Test>;
            })}
          </Fragment>
      })}
    </SidebarUI>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi @Vencovsky. The problem I see with your solution is that the previously clicked elements do not stay open. Because it's a collapse and the user didn't click to close them they should be left open.

Comment: @AxelJunes the OP didn't said how he wanted, but that is easy to change too. I will keep my answer and you keep your way too, then the OP have more options on what he want.

Comment: Yes, you're right that it wasn't specified in the question. @Yerlan Yeszhanov, can you edit the question to include it?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this without using state. Try changing to this

```
<Fragment key={idx}>
  <div class="sidebar-item" onClick={e => openSidebar(e)}>
    {item.name}
  </div>

  {item.data.map((subs, ids) => {
   return (
      <div className="sidebar-subitem" key={ids}>
        ++++{subs.name}
      </div>
    );
  })}
</Fragment>
```

Toggle class on click

```
 function openSidebar(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.classList.toggle("open");
  }
```

Add css

```
.sidebar-subitem {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar-item.open + .sidebar-subitem {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is of course not better than @axeljunes but will work too, so I've maintained a separate list of toggled id's and based on that it will toggle.
Also this is my first time using hooks so bare me(feel free to correct me)

```
const Sidebar = ({ title, children, data, opened, ...attrs }) => {
  //const [isOpen, setTriger] = useState(false);
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = idx => {
    //setTriger(!isOpen);
    if(!list.includes(idx))
      setList([...list,idx]);
    else{      
      const newList = list.filter(e => e!==idx);
      setList(newList);
    }

  };
  return (
    <SidebarUI>
      {data.map((item, idx) => {
        return typeof item.data === "string" ? (
          <div key={idx}>{item.name}MAIN</div>
        ) : (
          <Fragment key={idx}>
            <div onClick={() => handleClick(idx)}>{item.name}IN</div>

            {item.data.map((subs, ids) => {
              return (
                <Test isOpen={list.includes(idx)} key={ids}>
                  ++++{subs.name}SIDE
                </Test>
              );
            })}
          </Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </SidebarUI>
  );
};
export default Sidebar;
```